# Flutter | How to listen for navigation event?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, is there any way to listen for navigation changes?

Example: Navigation is triggered in `Widget A`:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/chat');
```

When the above code is executed, I want an event to fire in a child of `Widget A`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11):

Use RouteObserver :

```
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
```

then add this to root materialApp widget :

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
)
```

we need to implement RouteAware in every widget that might be push or pop into the routes stack.

```
class Screen extends State<Screen3> with RouteAware{
...

 @override
 void didChangeDependencies() {
   super.didChangeDependencies();
   routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute<dynamic>);
 }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    final route = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;
    print('didPush route: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    final route = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;
    print('didPopNext route: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    final route = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;
    print('didPushNext route: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    final route = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;
    print('didPop route: $route');
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I needed to make these changes:
```routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute<dynamic>);``` 
and 
```final route = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;```

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar problem and in my case, the best solution was using `MaterialApp`'s `onNavigationNotification`, like this:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  onNavigationNotification: (notification) {
    print('something changed');
    // your logic to notify your widget
    return notification.canHandlePop;
  },
);
```

This way, you'll get notified when a navigation event occurs and you can add your own logic for notifying `Widget A` that a navigation event happened. To notify `Widget A`, or any widgets inside your app, you could use a [`ChangeNotifier`](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier) or [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)'s `Bloc`, for example.

This solution worked great for me because I just needed to notify a widget when something happened in the navigation stack, and I used `ModalRoute`'s `isCurrent` to check if the widget was still part of the current route after the navigation event occurred.